# Need advice with this function in a card game

Tags: python, oop

So I'm making a blackjack game, and here's how I've defined the function for adding a card when the player calls for it:

```
def addcard(self):
    self.cards.append(self.a.deal())
    for a in range(0,len(self.cards)):
        self.value = self.value + values[self.cards[a]]
```

Values is a dictionary that assigns the card numbers to some value. Cards is a list defined under a 'Hand' class object. This hand class takes in as an attribute an instance of a seperate 'Deck' class(in this case its called a), which has the 'deal' function defined under it(the deal function just returns the first card in the deck). The problem is the values cards contains keys named as 'Two', 'Three', 'Jack' etc, while the deal function returns strings like 'Two of hearts', etc. Now, I can't change the key names, because this is how I chose to formulate the list of cards:

```
suits = ['Hearts','Spades','Diamonds','Clubs']
ranks = ['Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','King', 'Queen','Ace']
values = {'Two':2,'Three':3,'Four':4,'Five':5,'Six':6,'Seven':7,'Eight':8,'Nine':9,'Ten':10,'Jack':10,'King':10,'Queen':10,'Ace':11} 


class Deck:

def __init__(self):
    self.deck = []
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            self.deck.append(rank +' '+'of'+' '+suit)
```

So changing the keys will mess up my deck. Essentially what I need is to sort this mess out. Is there any way to index a list such that it only takes the first word of each element??

Comment: Change to `.deck.append(Card(rank, suit))` and at the point you need the string, do `print(<Card reference>)` which requires `Card.__str__():. return self.rank +' '+'of'+' '+ seld.suit`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but I'm assuming by your question

> Is there any way to index a list such that it only takes the first word of each element?

if you meant if there is a way to access a **dictionary** using the first word of a string? Then yes.

You can simply obtain the first word of the string by splitting it along any space character and then taking the first element as such

```
my_card = 'Two of Hearts'
my_card_rank = my_card.split(' ')[0]

print(values[my_card_rank])
```

Which should output: 2